# 8.19 LAB*: Program: Soccer team roster (Dictionaries)

Tags: python, dictionary

I keep getting these error messages. I have genuinely been working on it for over two hours and I dont know where to go from here.

**ASSIGNMENT:**

his program will store roster and rating information for a soccer team. Coaches rate players during tryouts to ensure a balanced team.

(1) Prompt the user to input five pairs of numbers: A player's jersey number (0 - 99) and the player's rating (1 - 9). Store the jersey numbers and the ratings in a dictionary. Output the dictionary's elements with the jersey numbers in ascending order (i.e., output the roster from smallest to largest jersey number). Hint: Dictionary keys can be stored in a sorted list. (3 pts)

Ex:

```
Enter player 1's jersey number:
84
Enter player 1's rating:
7

Enter player 2's jersey number:
23
Enter player 2's rating:
4

Enter player 3's jersey number:
4
Enter player 3's rating:
5

Enter player 4's jersey number:
30
Enter player 4's rating:
2

Enter player 5's jersey number:
66
Enter player 5's rating:
9

ROSTER
Jersey number: 4, Rating: 5
Jersey number: 23, Rating: 4
Jersey number 30, Rating: 2
...
```

(2) Implement a menu of options for a user to modify the roster. Each option is represented by a single character. The program initially outputs the menu, and outputs the menu after a user chooses an option. The program ends when the user chooses the option to Quit. For this step, the other options do nothing. (2 pts)

Ex:

```
MENU
a - Add player
d - Remove player
u - Update player rating
r - Output players above a rating
o - Output roster
q - Quit

Choose an option:
```

(3) Implement the "Output roster" menu option. (1 pt)

Ex:

```
ROSTER
Jersey number: 4, Rating: 5
Jersey number: 23, Rating: 4
Jersey number 30, Rating: 2
...
```

(4) Implement the "Add player" menu option. Prompt the user for a new player's jersey number and rating. Append the values to the two vectors. (1 pt)

Ex:

```
Enter a new player's jersey number:
49
Enter the player's rating:
8
```

(5) Implement the "Remove player" menu option. Prompt the user for a player's jersey number. Remove the player from the roster (delete the jersey number and rating). (1 pt)

Ex:

```
Enter a jersey number:
4
```

(6) Implement the "Update player rating" menu option. Prompt the user for a player's jersey number. Prompt again for a new rating for the player, and then change that player's rating. (1 pt)

Ex:

```
Enter a jersey number:
23
Enter a new rating for player:
6
```

(7) Implement the "Output players above a rating" menu option. Prompt the user for a rating. Print the jersey number and rating for all players with ratings above the entered value. (2 pts)

Ex:

```
Enter a rating:
5

ABOVE 5
Jersey number: 66, Rating: 9
Jersey number: 84, Rating: 7
```

**MY CODE:**

```
Roster1={
    'player 1':[],
    'player 2':[],
    'player 3':[],
    'player 4':[],
    'player 5':[]
    }
for n in range(5):
    jersey=int(input("Enter player %s"%(n+1)+"'s jersey number:\n"))
    rating=int(input("Enter player %s"%(n+1)+"'s rating:\n\n"))
    Roster1[f"player {n+1}"]=(int(jersey),int(rating))

sorted_roster = dict(sorted(Roster1.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][0]))

userchoice=''    

print("ROSTER")
for player, (jersey, rating) in sorted_roster.items():
    print(f'Jersey number: {jersey}, Rating: {rating}')
print('')
print("MENU")
print("a - Add player")
print("d - Remove player")
print("u - Update player rating")
print("r - Output players above a rating")
print("o - Output roster")
print("q - Quit")
print('\nChoose an option:')

while userchoice != 'q':
    userchoice=str(input())
    
    if userchoice=='q':
        break
    elif userchoice=='o':
        print()
        print("ROSTER")
        for player, (jersey, rating) in sorted_roster.items():
            print(f'Jersey number: {jersey}, Rating: {rating}')
        continue
    elif userchoice=='a':
        addjersey=str(input("Enter a jersey number:\n"))
        addrate=str(input("Enter a new rating for player:\n"))
        sorted_roster["player 6"]=(addjersey,addrate)
        sorted_roster = dict(sorted(Roster1.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][0]))
        print("ROSTER")
        for player, (jersey, rating) in sorted_roster.items():
            print(f'Jersey number: {jersey}, Rating: {rating}')
        print('')
        print("MENU")
        print("a - Add player")
        print("d - Remove player")
        print("u - Update player rating")
        print("r - Output players above a rating")
        print("o - Output roster")
        print("q - Quit")
        print('\nChoose an option:')
    
    elif userchoice=='d':
        removejersey=int(input("Enter a jersey number:\n"))
        for player,(jersey,rating) in sorted_roster.items():
            if jersey==removejersey:
                del sorted_roster[player]
        print()
        for player, (jersey, rating) in sorted_roster.items():
            print(f'Jersey number: {jersey}, Rating: {rating}')
        print('')
        print("MENU")
        print("a - Add player")
        print("d - Remove player")
        print("u - Update player rating")
        print("r - Output players above a rating")
        print("o - Output roster")
        print("q - Quit")
        print('\nChoose an option:')
    elif userchoice=='r':
        above=int(input("Enter a rating\n"))
        print(f'ABOVE {above}')
        sorted_roster = dict(sorted(Roster1.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][0]))
        for player, (jersey, rating) in sorted_roster.items():
            if rating>above:
                print(f'Jersey number: {jersey}, Rating: {rating}')
        print('')
        print("MENU")
        print("a - Add player")
        print("d - Remove player")
        print("u - Update player rating")
        print("r - Output players above a rating")
        print("o - Output roster")
        print("q - Quit")
        print('\nChoose an option:')
```

**ERRORS IM GETTING:

(SEE ATTATCHED IMAGE)**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYEKN.jpg)

Ive genuinely been working at this for hours and I feel like I tried everything

Comment: This image is very hard to read. Please copy and paste the error as text in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the size of a dictionary that youre looping through, this is what it says.
The reason being, if you delete an item the loop will eventually end up out of bounds. this is a safety measure.

```
for player,(jersey,rating) in sorted_roster.items():
            if jersey==removejersey:
                del sorted_roster[player]
```

the last line is where you changed the size.
What you could do instead is, you could collect all the players' indices (in the for loop) and delete them using those (using another loop that you could sort in descending order).

Hope that helps.